# architectural patterns for developing on android

Tags: android, design-patterns, architecture

I'm starting Android app development and just after my very first app more complex than *Hello World* I found out that you cannot hold any state in Activity because Android will recreate them in some cases... ouch, failure.
I'm guessing that strict model separation from view is a common practice, even for simple apps. Are there any settled patters I should follow? Some variant of Model-View-Controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should definitely read the [Application Fundamentals Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html)

In my experience, my design patterns in Android have been driven by the use of `Intents`, `Activities`, `Services`, `Broadcast receivers` and so forth.

I wouldn't say that "strict model separation from view is a common practice". You can keep data inside an Activity, but you will be forced to preserve it. Luckily this is made trivial by methods like `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` where persistent data members can be saved to a `Bundle` and then retrieved from the same `Bundle`.